# Can not install Visual Studio 2017

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2017 on my Windows 10 Machine. I have tried as both an adminstrator and not as an administrator.
I get the following errors and install fails:

```
The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures.

Incomplete workloads
    Desktop development with C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop,version=15.0.26403.0)
    Linux development with C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeCrossPlat,version=15.0.26323.1)
    Node.js development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node,version=15.0.26323.1)
    Visual Studio core editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26228.0)

Incomplete components
    Architecture tools for C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.ArchitectureTools.Native,version=15.0.26208.0)
    C++ profiling tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.DiagnosticTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Class Designer (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ClassDesigner,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Code Map (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CodeMap,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Connectivity and publishing tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Common.Azure.Tools,version=1.9.170119.3)
    Developer Analytics tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AppInsights.Tools,version=15.0.26323.1)
    DGML editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.GraphDocument,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Graphics debugger and GPU profiler for DirectX (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Tools,version=15.0.26208.0)
    JavaScript and TypeScript language support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript,version=15.0.26412.1)
    JavaScript diagnostics (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.Diagnostics,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Just-In-Time debugger (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Node.js support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Node.Tools,version=15.0.26323.1)
    Profiling tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Text Template Transformation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Visual C++ core desktop features (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Core,version=15.0.26323.1)
    Visual C++ for Linux Development (Component.MDD.Linux,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Visual C++ tools for CMake (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Visual Studio C++ core features (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreIde,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Visual Studio core editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Web Deploy (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WebDeploy,version=15.0.26208.0)
    WebSocket4Net (Component.WebSocket,version=15.0.26208.0)

You can search for solutions using the information below, modify your selections for the above workloads and components and retry the installation, or remove the product from your machine.

Following is a collection of individual package failures that led to the incomplete workloads and components above. To search for existing reports of these specific problems, please copy and paste the URL from each package failure into a web browser. If the issue has already been reported, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, you can create a new issue where other people will be able to find solutions or workarounds.

Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell,version=15.0.26430.4' failed to install.
    Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=-2147024864
    Impacted workloads
        Desktop development with C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop,version=15.0.26403.0)
        Linux development with C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeCrossPlat,version=15.0.26323.1)
        Node.js development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node,version=15.0.26323.1)
        Visual Studio core editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26228.0)
    Impacted components
        Architecture tools for C++ (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.ArchitectureTools.Native,version=15.0.26208.0)
        C++ profiling tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.DiagnosticTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Class Designer (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ClassDesigner,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Code Map (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CodeMap,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Connectivity and publishing tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Common.Azure.Tools,version=1.9.170119.3)
        Developer Analytics tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AppInsights.Tools,version=15.0.26323.1)
        DGML editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.GraphDocument,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Graphics debugger and GPU profiler for DirectX (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Tools,version=15.0.26208.0)
        JavaScript and TypeScript language support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript,version=15.0.26412.1)
        JavaScript diagnostics (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.Diagnostics,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Just-In-Time debugger (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Node.js support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Node.Tools,version=15.0.26323.1)
        Profiling tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Text Template Transformation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Visual C++ core desktop features (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Core,version=15.0.26323.1)
        Visual C++ for Linux Development (Component.MDD.Linux,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Visual C++ tools for CMake (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Visual Studio C++ core features (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreIde,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Visual Studio core editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Web Deploy (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WebDeploy,version=15.0.26208.0)
        WebSocket4Net (Component.WebSocket,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Log
        C:\TEMP\dd_setup_20170615130916_003_Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.log
    Details
        Return code: -2147024864
        Return code details: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\CheckHyperVHost.exe' because it is being used by another process.
```

I ran `handle` for `CheckHyperVHost.exe` and it does not show any program with a handle to that file.

Additionally, I checked [this similar question](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25856/the-product-failed-to-install-the-listed-workloads-4.html?childToView=53833#comment-53833) and confirmed that I have no antivirus software installed on this machine.

Comment: Are you running the installer as an administrator?

Comment: @hellyale Updated question. Yes I am.